# Cant able to install SSIS using BIDS

Tags: ssis

Just now i have started learning SSIS using BIDS .
I don't have BIDS installed in my machine and I am not able to do this..
can u give me any reference site or P.D.F from where I can get the detail idea of about all the control flows and data flows of SSIS?

Comment: What's your question is about? Is it Installation issue or Learning basics of SSIS??

Comment: facing both ..m not able to install SSIS as well as need some Learning basics of SSIS..
detail discussion abt the ctrl flows and data flows

Comment: What issue are you facing in installation? It bundled with developer or higher edition of any Sql Server version. Shouldn't be the problem. For learning there's plenty of online article that you can find to start :)

Comment: I have installed sql server 2008 R2 .. but i didnt get the option to install BIDS ..
Integration service has been installed it's showin.but i need to work with BIDS .. does sql 2008 support it?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious reference site for SSIS is [the SSIS site on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc511477).

You'll have to provide a lot more in the way of details before anyone can help with BIDS installation issues.